# git merge Localizable.strings file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, git, merge

I'm trying to configure git to work with merging Localizable.strings files on an iOS project. somehow, i noticed that xCode can open the files properly, but git doesn't know how. git treats all .strings files as binary files.

i tried to follow the directions here:

http://blog.xk72.com/post/31456986659/diff-strings-files-in-git

but it's not working for me -> when i do a `git merge`, git still doesn't show me the conflicts with `<<<<<` `=====` and `>>>>` in the files. specifically, i get this output:

```
fatal: bad config file line 41 in .git/config
```

where my config file on line 41 looks like:

```
 41 [diff “localizablestrings”]
 42     textconv = “iconv -f utf-16 -t utf-8”
```

how do i configure git to recognize and properly merge `*.strings` files?

i also checkedout some of the tools, such as: http://www.loc-suite.org/ but it has 0 documentation.

===================== UPDATE:

okay, so it turns out the double quotes i copy and pasted from html is bad. * facepalm *.

but now even when i merge, i still don't see the git merge conflict markers (`>>>>>` and `<<<<<`). is git still not merging these files as text files?

Comment: did you add `*.strings diff=localizablestrings` to your `.gitattributes` like that article describes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use xCode's merge feature.